# One to many queryset in django

Tags: python, django

I have 2 tables, Item and UserDetail. In table Item, I have item_id and item_name like this:
[image]

My UserDetail table like this:
[image]

I need to get user's username, and their most recent updated(e.g, Tina's education level was BSc on 05/01/2015 and changed to MSc on 05/01/2017. So I have to pick MSc for her education level),  email, home phone, cellphone and education information. For any missing info, I leave it as blank. So my result would be:

```
[{'username':John, 'email':'john@abs.com', 'homePhone':'', 'cellPhone':'', 'education':''},
 {'username':Jade, 'email': jade@email.com, 'homePhone':111 456-7890, 'cellPhone':'','education':''},
{'username':Tina, 'email':'', 'homePhone':'', 'cellPhone':'211 234-5678', 'education':'Msc'},]
```

Currently, I have queryset like this in my view.py:

```
items=Item.objects.filter(Q(item_id__in=(2, 3, 4, 6))).values('item_name').order_by('item_id')

users=[username1, username2, ...]
for user in users:
    users_data = UserDetail.objects.filter(username=username)\
          .filter(Q(id__in=(2,3, 4, 6)).values('id','record')\
          .order_by('id').latest(DateRecorded)
    qs1=[user]
    for item in items:
         for value in users_data:
             user_data=''
             if item['item_id']== value['id']:
                  user_data=value['record']
                  break
         qs1.append(data)
    qs2.append(qs1)
```

This works OK. However, the format of qs2 is not exactly the one I expected. I am getting qs2 like this:

```
[[u'John', u'john@abs.com', u'', u'', u''],
 [u'Jade', u'jade@email.com', u'111 456-7890',u'',u''],
[u'Tina', u'', u'', u'211 234-5678', u'mac'],]
```

Also, it takes more time to get the result back. Does anyone have good suggestion on this?

Add more comments on this:

Right now, I have data like this:

```
users_data= <QuerySet [{u'username': u'john', u'id': u'2', u'record': u'joh@abc.com'}, 
{u'username': u'jade', u'id': u'2', u'record': u'jade@email.com'},   
{u'username': u'jade', u'id': u'3', u'record': u'111 456-7890'}....]
```

Would prefer to construct the final data like:

```
by_username = [{u'username': u'john', u'email': u'joh@abc.com'},  
{u'username': u'jade', u'homePhone': u'111 456-7890'}]
```

So when I render the data in templates, I can access data as i.username, i.email, i.homePhone, i.cellPhone, i.education. This way, if user has any item missing, it will display as blank, like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It would perhaps make sense to use a formal `ForeignKey` relationship between `Item` and `UserDetail` since that relationship is one to many.

```
class UserDetail(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

You could then query the data you want more efficiently:

```
usernames = [username1, username2, ...]
items = [2, 3, 4, 6]
users_data = UserDetail.objects.filter(username__in=usernames, item__in=items)\
      .select_related('item')\
      .order_by('item_id').latest(DateRecorded)
```

And then structure the result how you need it:

```
from collections import defaultdict

by_username = defaultdict(dict)

for user_data in users_data:
    by_username[user_data['username']]['username'] = user_data['username']
    by_username[user_data['username']][user_data.item.item_name] = [user_data.record]

return by_username.values()
```

Comment: Thank you @Will! However, after querying UserDetail, users_data becomes:<QuerySet [{u'username': u'john', u'id': u'2', u'record': u'john@abc.com'}, {u'username': u'jade', u'id': u'2', u'record': u'jade@email.com'}, {u'username': u'jade', u'id': u'3', u'record': u'111 456-7890'}....]
My goal is to combine item id and  associated record for the user like:
[{u'username': u'john', u'email': u'joh@abc.com'}, {u'username': u'jade', u'homePhone': u'111 456-7890'}].

Comment: Yes the `users_data` queryset that you see (presumably using your debugger?) will show the data un-grouped. The code that then follows uses a `defaultdict` to group and structure the data in the format that you require. What do you see as the output of `by_username.values()`?

Comment: I can get username for by_username[user_data['username']]['username']. However, I am getting Attribute error for user_data.item_name.

Comment: Yes, you need to use `user_data.item.item_name`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clearly understand your database structure. But if you want the latest records you can get them!

```
queryset = UserDetail.objects.all().latest('date_recorded').distinct()
```

also you can add filter for obtaining ids in ids or whatever you want.
I've also applied distinct() on the queryset in order to have only unique records